# Difference in reading 下に: When to use しも.に or した.に

Tags: readings, word-usage

As I observed, `下に` can be read in two ways: `しも.に` and `した.に`.

- As far as I know, `した.に` can be used to indicate objects spacial arrangement.
- How about `しも.に`? Dictionary says that it also means `down; below; downward` ([source](https://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%97%E3%82%82%E3%81%AB))

When to use each reading form?